# How do I compute the determinant of (AA^T) where A is a not square

Tags: linear-algebra

A = \begin{bmatrix}2&-3&4&-2\\7&1&0&3\\4&-2&11&6\\3&2&-6&2\\-2&5&3&-1\end{bmatrix}

Compute det(AA^T).

My guess is that the determinant is 0, but that depends if A is linear independent. I'm unsure where to proceed.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is "You don't".

Answer (score 5):

You cannot find the determinant of a non-square matrix. On the other hand, the product $A A^T$ is 5 by 5 and has a determinant. Since $A A^T$ has rank at most 4, that determinant is zero.

In the other order, the product is 4 by 4, has integer entries, is symmetric, and could easily have a nonzero determinant, which would then be positive as the product is positive definite. This is a common construction for number theory of integer lattices (quadratic forms). If you look [HERE](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/) there is, for each lattice, a "basis" which is a rectangular matrix more often than not.

Comment: Consider to take a look at this page:  en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: How does AAT have rank of 4? isn't A linear independent so wouldnt the 5x5 matrix have rank of 5?

Comment: @twenty40, each factor has rank at most 4.